# How to Programatically Turn on Guided Access on iPad/iOS Device?

Tags: ios, ipad, selenium, appium

I am currently automating an app for iPad that needs to be set in Guided Access mode to work. I'm using Java with Selenium webdriver inside Eclipse. The app is all setup and being deployed through Xcode and I can interact with it just fine with the iOS driver.

The problem is the user cannot login until the iPad is set to Guided Access mode on this app. I know you can turn it on by triple clicking the Home button very quickly but I have not found a way to do that using code inside my tests.

Is there a way to send keyevents specific to the iPad Home button OR is there a way to set Guided Access mode programatically? Maybe set it in the capabilities before the iOS driver/app launches?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to send events to the home button (pretty sure this wouldn't be possible).

You can programmatically enable / disable guided access however, using UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession. In order for this to work, your device must be supervised using MDM and have a profile installed that enables single app mode for your application.

More details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession